# Python GTK+3: Keep title to the left?

Tags: python, gtk3

So right now, I'm building a window with a title set sort of like this:

```
hb = Gtk.HeaderBar()
self.title = "Some string"
hb.set_decoration_layout(None)
hb.props.custom_title = Gtk.Label(label=self.title)
self.set_titlebar(hb)
```

There are cases when the window changes size. However, the title repositions itself to be centered no matter what the size (which is to be expected). I would like the keep the title always in the top left corner of my window. Is there a way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: You can tune `xalign` property (probably you will also need to adjust `hexpand` prop).

Comment: Still can't seem to get it to work. Would it be posible to do it through the CSS?